# How do I place a application list icon in the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, menu, appmenu

If I click Dash and then the second tab (Search Applications), one of the items available is "Installed Applications".

Is there anyway to put a quick link to this in the launcher? Basically a icon like home that will instead open a list of all installed applications?

Comment: Is it possible to have the main menu back while still using unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used Cardapio and applied a launcher for it. Works good and solved my problem.

[image]

**From the [Cardapio Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/cardapio) page:**

## Installation in Ubuntu

Cardapio can easily be installed in Ubuntu versions 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) and up. Simply follow the steps below:

1) Run these commands in a terminal:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/cardapio-ppa && sudo
  apt-get update`

2) Now pick one or more of these, depending on how you want to use Cardapio:

- `sudo apt-get install cardapio-gnomepanel`  (to install the
  Gnome-Panel applet)
- `sudo apt-get install cardapio-docky`      (to    install the
  Docky applet)
- `sudo apt-get install cardapio-awn`           (to install the AWN
  applet)
- `sudo apt-get install    cardapio-gnomeshell`  (to install the
  Gnome-Shell applet)
- `sudo    apt-get install cardapio`            (to use it in
  stand-alone    mode only)

3) Done!

If you want to use as a Unity Launcher item as depicted in the screenshot above, then

- install the stand-alone version as instructed above
- run this command in a terminal: `cardapio hidden`
- then use the following instructions from this [Webupd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/use-classic-menu-in-unity-classicmenu.html):

*So download the Cardapio launcher from [HERE](http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/cardapio.tar.gz), extract it and place the file under ~/.local/share/applications/ (important: if you don't place it here, it will disappear once you restart your computer). ".local" is a hidden folder in your home directory so press CTRL + H to see it. Then drag the file to the Unity Launcher.*

Frequently Asked questions can be found at [Cardapio FAQs page](https://answers.launchpad.net/cardapio/+faqs).

Comment: Development of Cardapio has [halted](https://launchpad.net/cardapio/+announcement/11268) and Ubuntu 12.10 is the last version to have a PPA for it.